# How i can pass multi property of class as parameter of method using C#

Tags: c#

I have a class that will be inherit in onother class. The content of class:

```
public T First(Expression<Func<T, string>> OrderBy = null)
{
   string orderby=string.Empty;
   if (OrderBy != null)
   {
      System.Reflection.PropertyInfo orderbyinfo= (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)  ((MemberExpression)OrderBy.Body).Member;
            orderby = orderbyinfo.Name;
   }
   ...
```

}

But error "Can not convert lambda expression to delegate type ..." with method:

```
public T First(Expression<Func<T, string>> OrderBy = null,Expression<Func<T, string>> GroupBy = null)
{
   string orderby=string.Empty;
   string groupby=string.empty
   if (OrderBy != null)
   {
      System.Reflection.PropertyInfo orderbyinfo= (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)   ((MemberExpression)OrderBy.Body).Member;
            orderby = orderbyinfo.Name;
   }

   if (GroupBy != null)
   {
      System.Reflection.PropertyInfo groupbyinfo= (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)  ((MemberExpression)GroupBy.Body).Member;
            groupby = groupbyinfo.Name;
   }
   ...
```

}

And method as:

```
Article article = new Article();
article.Title="test";
article=article.First(x=>x.Title,y=>y.Status);
```

Please help me! thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide the complete error output.

Comment: And a complete code example. And a complete problem description. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because `Status` probably isn't a `string` and your `Func`s can return only a `string`:

```
public T First(
    Expression<Func<T, string>> orderBy = null,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> groupBy = null)
```

if you make them generic you'll be able to return anything. Because both properties can be of different types you'll need two generic types (`TProperty1` `TProperty2`), one for each of them:

```
public T First<TProperty1, TProperty2>(
    Expression<Func<T, TProperty1>> orderBy = null, 
    Expression<Func<T, TProperty2>> groupBy = null)
```

Example:

```
class C<T>
{        

    public T First<TProperty1, TProperty2>(
        Expression<Func<T, TProperty1>> orderBy = null, 
        Expression<Func<T, TProperty2>> groupBy = null)
    {
        string orderByName = string.Empty;
        string groupByName = string.Empty;
        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo orderByInfo = (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)orderBy.Body).Member;
            orderByName = orderByInfo.Name;
        }

        if (groupBy != null)
        {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo groupByInfo = (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)groupBy.Body).Member;
            groupByName = groupByInfo.Name;
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

Usage: here both properties are `int`s

```
new C<string>().First(x => x.Length, x => x.Length);
```

---

However if they must be `string`s then you need to convert/cast the values to `string`s:

```
article = article.First(x=>x.Title, y=>y.Status.ToString());
```

---

Would you have read all error messages and posted all of them here you would have noticed that there is a line that tells you about the conversion error:

> Error 1   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
>
> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: @HienPhamMinh I've missed the detial that both properties may be of different types. See my edited answer.